# How to render all Video frames through canvas in android

Tags: android

I am very beginner to android OS.

I am writing a media player and I get frames from the native code and will be displayed from java code as bitmaps. I convert frames from bytes array into bitmaps and then display it. Right now I am able to display one frame, but i am unable to display them continuously.

My code is as below

canvas.drawbitmap(mbitmap,0,0,null);

but when i am trying to display the next frame, it is still displaying the same previous frame and not changing. Do I need to clear the bitmap or something? Or is there any otherway to draw the rendered frames.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Can u tell me how to get frames from playing video?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In android developers page, you can [see](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#frame-animation)

the explanation for frame animation!

Answer (score 1):

Something similar at [this repo](https://github.com/Moriarty16/MediaCodec.git).

Comment: can you be more specific with this repository, how will it solve the question, only a link doesn't look like an answer